# Random behavior due to a file conflict running a Jekyll theme locally?

Tags: jekyll, scss-mixins, jekyll-theme

I have, in some unexplained way, managed to get my first Jekyll site with the "Agency" theme running locally.
However, there is something that is still not right. I extracted all the files from the biggest zip file of the theme, which seem to cover all files.

First I must point out that I'm not using GitHub at all for my site. Using only local resources on my Windows machine (afaik), and I'm developing by browsing http://localhost:4000.

I get this warning:

```
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
          Conflict: The following destination is shared by multiple files.
                    The written file may end up with unexpected contents.
                    C:/web/_site/assets/css/agency.css
                     - assets/css/agency.scss
                     - C:/web/assets/css/agency.css

                    ...done in 0.1660095 seconds.
```

This creates strange behaviour. I run these commands:

`bundle update`
`bundle exec jekyll serve`

... The site works perfectly until I make some changes that make the style of the page go bananas. I assume it has to do with the warning of the CSS file. It's like it reverts back to some default CSS and my latest changes won't show.

When running the serve command everything auto-updates anyway. The CSS warning conflict never goes away though.

In my _confg.yml file, I could run any of these lines (or comment them both out) and it will work:

```
theme: raviriley/agency-jekyll-theme
remote_theme: raviriley/agency-jekyll-theme
```

I'm still confused in general about how Jekyll works and what might have happened in my case. Hope someone can help me solve the conflict thing.

Comment: Please share your agency.scss and agency.css code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have changed in your CSS but I cannot reproduce your issues using the Agency theme locally on Windows (I have downloaded the theme [here](http://jekyllthemes.org/themes/agency/) and copied all files).

By default, the `_config.yml` file contains this line for the theme: `theme: jekyll-agency`. After running bundle and starting the jekyll server, I can see the page. Any modification, such as `* { color: red }` shows fine, I don't get errors in the logs.

##### One difference to your version

There is no **agency.css** file but only the SCSS version of it. The SCSS file is localed in assets\css\agency.scss

This file imports all the other variables and styles. The styles are placed in scss files in these three folders:

- base
- components
- variables

Of course, you can also add styles to the agency.scss file but I would not do it, the component/layout structure makes sense. Read about the Sass Basics here: https://sass-lang.com/guide